# how to make a social networking sharing buttons with floating attributes in wordpress

Tags: button, twitter, facebook-like, google-plus-one, pinterest

i wanna know how am i able to add a social media buttons in my wordpress template. I would like to have a Facebook like, google plus, pinterest pin it and twitter tweet button floating on the left side of my wordpress body.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial on [how to add floating facebook like, twitter tweet, google plus one and pinterest button](http://www.bendaggers.com/how-to-make-a-floating-facebook-like-twitter-tweet-google-plus-one-pinterest-pin-it-in-your-wordpress-theme/,) can help you. It also comes with a feature that whenever your screen resolution is low, it will auto hide.